# Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of org/zmlx/hg4idea/HgFile. must not be null

Tags: mercurial, android-studio, bitbucket

I have a project in android studio and I have imported it to BitBucket successfully using the BitBucket Plugin for android. But now when I make changes in the project, the following error shows up in log:

```
Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of org/zmlx/hg4idea/HgFile.  must not be null
```

I cannot commit the file. Is there any configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was that the VCS type get set to `Mercurial` by default. I had to change it to GIT.